# How to Stop "Salesforce Error" Emails Reporting Batch Apex errors

Tags: salesforce, apex

We regularly receive automated emails from Salesforce about Batch Apex errors, but are having trouble 1) disabling the error emails and 2) tracking down the issues. Is there a way to disable these error messages (many people in the organization receive them regularly and I'd rather that just one user, if any, receive it)? Is there a way to see specifically which Apex script is triggering these errors or get any more information about the error?

Here is an example error message:

```
Organization: Organization Name(0000000000000000)
User: email@gmail.com(0000000000000000)

Salesforce reported the below errors as NPSP was attempting to execute its batch jobs, or at a time when it was unable to display error messages directly to a user. It’s likely that NPSP was attempting to update summary fields on Accounts and Contacts, but was unable to save certain records. This failure might have been caused by a variety of issues unrelated to NPSP, such as custom code or validation rules.

Read this article on the Power of Us Hub to learn how these Scheduled Jobs work: https://powerofus.force.com/NPSP_Scheduled_Jobs

If you’re not sure how to resolve these errors, post a message in the Nonprofit Success Pack group in the Power of Us Hub: https://powerofus.force.com/HUB_NPSP_Group


Errors:

----------
 Error #1:

Error Type: Batch Apex error
Error Date: 2017-09-11 04:00:25
Message: "First error: Update failed. First exception on row 0 with id 003i000001ILolWAAT; first error: FIELD_CUSTOM_VALIDATION_EXCEPTION, Please enter a Mailing Country.: []"
Context: npsp__RLLP_OppSoftCreditRollup_BATCH

Stack Trace:
 null
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is not a standard email sent by the platform.  This is a custom email sent by the NPSP, which you must have installed.

If you don't need these batch processes to work, you can stop them from running by going to Setup | Scheduled Jobs.

If you do need them to run, then you can just go to the record indicated in the error Contact 003i000001ILolWAAT and populate the Mailing Country.  You could also turn off the validation rule requiring Mailing Country or update it not to apply to your user so that when the batch process runs it will be able to get past it.